# Adsense payment taking a month from when issued until it arrives in my account

Tags: google-adsense, payments

I have an AdSense account that has been active for a few year now. I have received payments in the past using Wire-Transfer to my bank account. I have not changed my back account also not messed with any settings In AdSense.

Everything is unchanged.

I got a payout on **21 may** from Adsense which was deposited to my bank on **30-may**

then I got another payout on **21-Aug** from Adsense which was deposited to my bank on **27-Sept**. Yeah, a whole month late.

Now I got another payout on **21-oct** from AdSense, and **no money has been deposited** yet to my bank account.

Will I have to wait another month for the payment?

The amount has been deducted from my AdSense account as I mentioned.

When I received payment late for August, I thought that it was a one-off thing. But apparently, it has happened again.

I have contacted my bank and they say that they have not received any payment and no payments for my account are pending.

I am from India.

There is one more thing I noticed is that When the payment was on time, the account details of my bank showed the following

```
Forex Txn USD XXX.xx  @ XXX.xx GOOGLE ASIA ABCDEFGHIJKLM
```

And when the payment was delayed for Aug which I got on Sept the back transaction detail show the following

```
Forex Txn TT PAID USD XXX.xx @ XX.xx  ABCDEFGHIJKLM
```

Notice that **GOOGLE ASIA** did not show up on the payout that was late.

Comment: If you earn less than $100 in a particular month you may have to wait for successive months to accrue more than $100 before they actually make a payout to you. Is that what's happening?

Comment: I don't think the $100 is the issue here.   They say that Google attempted to send the payment and the amount was deducted from AdSense.   It is just taking a long time to appear in the bank account.

Comment: yes..@Octopus I am aware of the threshold lmit..It is not that..The payment has been made by google and deducted from Adsense account..But not appeared in my Bank Account..The last payment was delayed by a month as I mentioned